# EdgeLight: Screen borders are not going beyond the notch and softkeys in react native

Tags: android, react-native, border

I am just trying to implement "edge light" Ref in react native.

I have this below code to achieve it.

`<Layout style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 18, paddingBottom: 18, paddingLeft: 28, paddingRight: 28, borderWidth: 10, borderColor: '#36ABA5', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#000', color: '#fff' }}> // All my code </Layout>`

This seems to be working fine for the mobiles which are having straigh screens. But I am facing 2 issues,

1. The same is not working when the mobile has notch or the mobile's softkeys are enabled.
2. In Honor 8x the border itself is not coming when softkeys are disabled, when those are enabled, the border comes above the softkeys.

I tried calculating the window height, screen height and put the border. It seems to be not happening.

**In Straight phone**

[image: In Straight phone:]

**In Notch phone:**

[image: In Notch phone:]

**In Softkeys enabled:**

[image]

**In Softkeys disabled:**

[image: In Softkeys disabled:]

**Wanted similar to this, but not colorful/ Expected Results:**

**[image: Wanted similar to this, but not colorful/ Expected Results:]**

Comment: can you provide you react-native version?

Comment: react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: 0.61.5 => 0.61.5
Please find.

Comment: and can you give snack demo code so I can try to figure out?

Comment: can you give any snack demo?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `Layout` element from whatever library you are using automatically adjusts paddings to avoid unsafe areas (like notches and navigation bars). So don't use it, use a simple `View` with `flex: 1`

After that, if you are still not able to draw behind status bar and navigation bar, edit `styles.xml` (`android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml`), to add these 2 entires to `<style name="AppTheme" ...>` tag:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Comment: Hi, I am using normal borders to make it. is there any way to trigger the inbuild edge lights?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I did not find any solution to trigger the inbuilt border lights from react-native or any other solution to replicate it.

I did an alternative solution, made the status bar colored and softkeys colored.